# What's different between "so ... that" and "so that" sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

As following two sentences,please tell help me to handle a couple of questions?
1.Are they the same meaning ?
2.If not ,how to use both and give me some sentences for both?
3.And please instruct about grammar with both?
4.If yes. how to use both in different scenario conditions?

> He is so good a boy that I like him.
>     VS
>   He is a good boy so that I like him.

other example
She made so good a meal that we all ate far too much
VS
She made a good meal so that we all ate far too much

Comment: No. *_so a good boy_ is ungrammatical; it should be _such a good boy_. One uses [_so_ before adjectives, but _such_ before noun phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/53311/15299). _So that_ is just _so_, indicating purpose, followed by a clause that begins with _that_; since _that_ is often deleted, it's usually the same as _so_ alone. _He closed the gate so (that) the dog wouldn't get out_.

Comment: @JohnLawler thanks for your comment, this sentence is from grammar book , so how can i do ???

Comment: Get a different grammar book. There are lots of bad ones.

Comment: sorry @JohnLawler I make a mistake, it should be "so good a man" ,by the way I still look at more information on website so i put more sentence at the question content